# AJAX PHP Blank POST Data Sent Godaddy

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I can't seem to get this simple script to work on a godaddy webserver but it works fine on my localhost. Any suggestions would be appreciated! Pretty much I've isolated that ajax is not passing the data to the other .php file, I just have no idea why. I've rewritten it many times now. It works fine locally, just not on my web server.

pleasework.php

```
<?php

?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.metroui.org.ua/v4.3.2/css/metro-all.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test"> please work..</p>
    <form>
        <button type="button" onclick="clickit()">test it</button>
    </form>
</body>
<script>
function clickit() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "worked.php",
        data: { workvariable: "I hope it worked" }
    })
    .done(function( response ) {
        alert("Success.");
        $("#test").html(response);
    })
    .fail(function()  {
        alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
    }); 
}
</script>
</html>
```

worked.php

```
<?php
    $workvariable = $_POST['workvariable'];
?>
<p id="pleasework">
<?php echo $workvariable; ?>
</p>
```

Comment: AJAX Code is Javascript, therefore it is run in the Browser, so its independant of your locahost or your godaddy server. Its run by you in your browser either way

Comment: Normally in the PHP that receives the AJAX request, there should be just code, not HTML. Treat it like a subroutine libraryTry this as `worked.php` sample `<?php
$workvariable = $_POST['workvariable'];
echo $workvariable;
exit;
?>`

Comment: Make sure you are using the right filenames. Windows filenames are not case-sensitive but centos/ubuntu filenames are.

Comment: Do some debugging. Open the browsers dev tools and check the console for errors. Also check the network tab while executing the ajax request and check if it's even making the request at all. If it does, check what data it actually sends and what the response from the server is.

Comment: Try to give the url as full path.  url: "worked.php", like url: {{domain.com/folder/}}"worked.php",

Comment: It looks like it was a path issue, I got it to work! Localhost doesn't seem to care, but once on the web server it needs to full path. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with the path. The Localhost which was WAMP didn't have any issue with it, but once on the web server it needed the full path.

Thank you everyone!